# Send bitcoin to entered wallet address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bitcoin

I'm trying to look through different APIs for bitcoin transactions, but havn't been able to find a clear path for what I'm trying to achieve. I was hoping some one could explain to me an easy way to send bitcoins based on the entered amount from the user on a form. I'm going to be using ruby on rails to create the site.

Answer (score 1):

With ruby on rails its very simple. Coinbase has its own gem: `gem 'coinbase'` which you can add to your gem file. Then simply look in the docs (https://coinbase.com/api/doc) and the source code (https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-ruby) of the gem to find what you need to do. Hope this helps!